# java.io.FileNotFoundException in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, filenotfoundexception

### Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

    private int colorStrength;
    private String color;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String line, file = "strength.txt";

        File openFile = new File(file);
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(openFile);

        while (inFile.hasNext()) {
            line = inFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        inFile.close();
    }
}
```

This is a small part of a program I am writing for a class (the two private attributes have yet to be used I know)  but when I try to run this with the strength.txt file I receive the following errors:

### Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: strength.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:14)
```

If anyone with Eclipse could help me figure this out it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is `strength.txt` co-located with `Driver.class`?

Comment: Yes it is.  I have it saved in the src folder of the program as well as the Project folder

Comment: It is not. @PM77-1 asked you to check if that is co-located with Driver.class. If you look at the `bin` directory, you would have seen only Driver.class unless you make the below mentioned change in either of the answers.

Comment: It is in the bin directory along with the Driver.class and still doesn't work

Comment: OK. Check the spelling.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've used a *relative* file path which is relative to your project execution.

If you'd like to do it that way, simply put the `strength.txt` file in the *base directory* of your project. Like so:

[image]

Alternatively, you could reference the `absolute` file path on your system. For example, use:

Windows:

`C:/dev/myproject/strength.txt`

Mac/Unix:

`/Users/username/dev/strength.txt`

(or whatever the full path may be) instead.

Comment: I put the file into the base directory as you said and it still gives me the same error code.  Do you have any other tips?

Comment: Hmm, works for me. Anyways, use the full path on your system then. Keep in mind that file paths are system *dependent*, so running it on a Windows machine will have different results than a Mac/Unix machine.

Comment: It should have worked. Try printing the absolute path as i mentioned below, and tell us what u get

Answer (score 3):

Do this

```
System.out.println(openFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

It will show you where JVM expects to find the file and whether it is the folder you expect as well, Accordingly place the file or give the exact location

Comment: If you do the above , you see that your file is in say C:\Harley\Test\strength.txt  ie: it is expecting the file in the project base directory.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to see what file path the system is using to reach the relative path

```
    System.out.print(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Then make sure that the relative path immediately follows this path.

You can also turn that into a string by doing

```
String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

and then you can just add that to the beginning of the filepath like so,

```
    ImageIcon imageIconRefVar = new ImageIcon(filePath + "/imagepathname");
```

I found this solved the issue for me when I used it in the path (which seemed odd since that should be the location it is in, but it worked)

Answer (score 2):

> You've used a relative file path which is relative to your project execution.

If this works for you, you can change the execution directory from the project root to the binary directory by:

1. "Run" -> "Run configurations"
2. In the "Arguments" tab, find "working directory" settings.
3. Switch from "Default" to "Other".
4. Click the "Workspace" button and select the project in pop-up window then click "OK"; this will bring you something like `$(workspace_loc:proj-1)`.
5. Append "/bin" to the end of it; save the configuration.

I need this instead of simply putting files in project root directory when I am doing assignment and the professor requires specific file hierarchy; in addition, this is more portable than absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the base directory create a folder, name it "res". Place your file inside "res" folder.

use `String file = ".\\res\\strength.txt";` to reference the location of your file.

You should use a resource folder to store all the files you use in your program (a good practice).

And make a refrence of that file from your root directory. So the file is present within the package.