# java FileNotFoundException wont locate a file in the same project

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception

I am writing a program for my comp sci class, andI keep getting the same error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:636)
    at Search.main(Search.java:18)
```

Here is the beginning of my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Search{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        Scanner inData = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));

        String data=inData.nextLine();
        String[] arr = data.split(" ");   

        while(inData.hasNext()){
            String search=inData.nextLine();
            int len=search.length();
            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I have a text file in the same Java Project, so I'm not sure what the problem is and I've tried moving the location of the file around but nothing is working.

Comment: do you have the file in the root level of the project?

Comment: Create a source folder as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9278270/1057230). Now access the file using `Scanner scanner = new Scanner ( Search.class.getResourceAsStream ( "data.txt" ) );` Or simply place the file inside `bin` folder.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne Yes

Comment: @nIcEcOw I'm getting a java.lang.NullPointerException when I do that

Comment: @OoOoOoOoOoO: If I follow the steps, as mentioned in my previous comment, then it is working fine, though I have to use `scanner = new Scanner ( ShowFile.class.getResourceAsStream ( "/files/data.txt" ) );`. Here is a [working project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kc20dzivmt0svzl/TestingFile.rar?dl=0). This project is made in `Eclipse Mars`. I just created a Source Folder named `resources` inside it I manually created a folder `files` and copied `data.txt` file to this folder `files`.

Answer (score 2):

The working path of your executed code can be determined with this code:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

Usually this is the target or the classes or the bin folder, depending on your IDE.

Comment: Once I find that out, how can I change that or put the text file there?

Comment: you simply browse your files system to the folder ... it is most of the time in your workspace. and place the `data.txt` there . What is the result of this System.out.println.. please ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the file `data.txt` in the root of your eclipse java project , outside your folder `/src/`.

[image]

Comment: is it like in the picture ?

Comment: Yes it looks exactly like that: Search, src, JRE... , data.txt

Comment: try `new File("/data.txt")` in the `Scanner` ?

Comment: is `data.txt` a *read-only* file ? check the properties of data.txt ? you are in which OS ?

Comment: what ever OSryx suggested u, it should work. Check these two links 1>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978170/java-io-filenotfoundexception-in-eclipse 2>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871955/java-io-filenotfoundexception-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified