# How to set OpenNLP Model binary file path in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, nlp, opennlp

I have downloaded the Binary model files from [here](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/) but i am not getting how do i have to set the path. I am using Eclipse, i tried adding these binary file into the path of my project.Second point is,I am not working on Maven Project.

```
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorME;
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel;
import opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class OpenNlpTest {

public static void SentenceDetect() throws InvalidFormatException,
IOException {
String paragraph = "Hi. How are you? This is Mike.";

// always start with a model, a model is learned from training data
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-sent.bin");
SentenceModel model = new SentenceModel(is);
SentenceDetectorME sdetector = new SentenceDetectorME(model);

String sentences[] = sdetector.sentDetect(paragraph);

System.out.println(sentences[0]);
System.out.println(sentences[1]);
is.close();

}
public static void main(String []z){

    try {
        SentenceDetect();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

this is the code i am trying to run but it gives the following error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: en-sent.bin (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at OpenNlpTest.SentenceDetect(OpenNlpTest.java:17)
at OpenNlpTest.main(OpenNlpTest.java:31)
```

This is the hierarchy of my project which i have just started
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: as you can see there is red indicator on the project.Just see what error it is saying in the error console

Comment: I resolved that error, it said that one of the archive or ZIP was corrupt. I removed that ZIP from the folder,now no red Exclamation is there but still the same output i am getting.

Comment: [This Helped me, Thanks, i should have thought the other way to search][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978170/java-io-filenotfoundexception-in-eclipse

Comment: You can always answer your question.There will be a Answer your question button at the bottom

Comment: OK there it is ,the answer. Thanks Madhan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution.

[This helped me to crack the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978170/java-io-filenotfoundexception-in-eclipse)
Basically what I did is  I gave the absolute path of the file rather than relative path.

Comment: Well, this is not a good solution as it does not scale on other environments.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see it is showing

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: de-sent.bin (The system cannot find the file specified)`

You haven't added necessary dependent libraries.In the link you've provided there is a bin named de-sent.bin.You have to add it to the library path

[image]

Comment: But i want to use "en-sent.bin" ie model file for english language, and therefore i have added this bin file only. You can check there is a column named "Language" on the lest most side.

Comment: I have tried it before, it gives the same Exception.Actually i think i have not given the proper path, if you can help me out with that that  would be great, i have already added OPENNPL_HOME and given the path of the directory in which i have kept all the bin files. Its still not Working.

Comment: after setting the path have you relaunched the eclipse.If not relaunch the eclipse coz it might be referring the old values

Comment: Actually Sorry I have posted the question incorrectly. When i try to use de-sent.bin it gives the same error as when i use en-sent.bin

Comment: No, the same Exception !