# Cannot access text file in java project

Tags: java

I am trying to access a text file, `output.txt` which is inside a project folder. The image below shows the folder structure.

[image]

```
String file=".\\testFiles\\output.txt";
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

When I try to access that file using the code above, I get the following exception.

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\testFiles\output.txt (No such file or directory)
```

I have tried different file path formats but none have worked. I think the problem is with the file path format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978170/java-io-filenotfoundexception-in-eclipse

Comment: In addition to the answers already given, please use forward slashes if you hardcode paths in Java.

Comment: guys thank you all of you for responses. Finally I settled for complete absolute path for time being. Next time I would surely refer all comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly you can get a folder/file in the current directory like so:

```
File folder = new File("testFiles");
```

Then you can open the file by getting the absolutePath and creating a new file with it, like so:

```
File file = new File(folder.getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + "output.txt");
```

I'm not sure but I think you can also do:

```
File file = new File("testFiles/output.txt");
```

I hope this helps :)

P.S. this is all  untested so it might not work.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the fact that you have a webcontent folder i presume this is a web project, possibly packaged as a war? In this case what you will want to do is package the respective files along with the classes and access it with something like this:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("output.txt")
```

The code above will work if you add the testFiles folder as a source folder (this means it will get packaged with the classes and be available at runtime)

The good thing is that this way the path can stay relative, no need to go absolute

Comment: +1 for The code above will work if you add the testFiles folder as a source folder (this means it will get packaged with the classes and be available at runtime)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem is due to the fact that you rely on a relative path as your path starts with a dot which means that it will by relative to the user directory (value of the system property `user.dir`) so I believe that your user directory is not what you expect. What you could do to debug is simply this:

```
System.out.println(new File(file).getAbsolutePath());
```

Thanks to this approach you will be able to quickly know if the absolute path is correct.

Answer (score -2):

You must declare your file as a new file:

```
File yourFile = new File("testFiles/output.txt");
```

Comment: 1.  No you don't have to do this.  2.  It won't fix the problem.