# Eclipse oxygen, Java: cannot run project

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, eclipse-oxygen, jad, jadclipse

project: lwjgl is installed because I am trying to make a 3d game. presently I am trying to figure out how Minecraft random terrain generation works. however i am unable to run the project.

When I try to run my project with plugins test in eclipse oxygen, it gives me the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Plugin directory test_plugins not found.
    at net.java.games.util.plugins.Plugins.scanPlugins(Plugins.java:82)
    at net.java.games.util.plugins.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:76)
    at net.java.games.util.plugins.test.PluginTest.<init>(PluginTest.java:92)
    at net.java.games.util.plugins.test.PluginTest.main(PluginTest.java:119)
```

when i click on any of the plugin names it only gives me:

```
unable to open external editor C\users\hp\desktop\Jad.exe
```

I have uninstalled any remnants of Jad or Jadclipse that i can find on my computer. am i doing something wrong? or is there something i might have overlooked?

I am trying to run the project as a java application, it then gives me 3 options: cache line size, plugins test, and XMP file. all 3 of these options give me error messages.

Comment: May be its a possible duplicate of this and can help you out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978170/java-io-filenotfoundexception-in-eclipse

Comment: yes, I saw that earlier. didn't help. I don't think it the same problem. is there a way to permanently delete jad from eclipse?

Comment: yes, Help->About eclipse-> installation details->installed software then uninstall whatever you want.

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't seem to have affected the problem.

Comment: What you actually want to do?

Comment: to run the project, that is possible in eclipse, correct?

Comment: Your comment is incomplete, mention in question details what your project is all about and what you want to do clearly -Shadow

Comment: Why have you installed  lwjgl? Specify whats your project all about?